# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Tags: flutter

shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
already using

```
 SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
 const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences')
      .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
      return <String, dynamic>{}; // set initial values here if desired
    }
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide the test snippet where you are setting this mock?